# Protractor throwing exception in synchronization between angular and non-angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

We are developing a protractor jasmine framework for testing the angular part of our application. When we run the script the protractor switches from non-angular to angular without any problem, however the exception is thrown when it switches back to non-angular part of application even after we use the property `igonoresynchroniztion`.

This is the Exception:

> 'root element(html) has no injector.This may mean it is not inside ng-app'.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: change your rootElement to body in your config

Comment: Check for directive 'ng-app' where it is placed? it would either in <body>,<html> or <div> in login.html or index.html

Comment: Actually we don't have the 'ng-app' in login.it lies in one of the sub tabs of our application.The thing is we only have a portion of our application built in angular js and rest is non angular and while navigating back to the sub tab built in non-angular we are getting the exception.

Comment: rootElement : '.<tag>' mention this parameter in your conf.js file